# How to query and get value from list in single document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongoengine

I am trying to query a mongodb list in a single document. As shown below, I would like to match the code and get wheels value. if code = car then query should return wheels and allowed value for that list element. Below is a list from single document.

```
"vehicles" : [ 
        {
            "code" : "car",
        "wheels":4,
            "allowed": True
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "Tuk Tuk",
        "wheels":4
            "allowed":True
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "Bike",
        "wheels":4
            "allowed":False
        }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this

`db.collectionName.find({"vehicles.code" : "car" }, {"vehicles.wheels" : 1 , "vehicles.allowed" : 1}).pretty()`
here "vehicles.code" : "car" is the filter and "vehicles.wheels" : 1 will display the only wheels value and won't display any other fields

Comment: this will return list of wheels and allowed value for the document including Tuk Tuk and Bike

Comment: It means it didn't apply the filter "vehicles.code" : "car" , Please check once with your query or else post the query

Comment: given code is list from single document. You are filtering documents in collection. But I want filter the list.

Comment: you may try like this   ` db.Vehiclestest.find({vehicles : {$elemMatch : {"code" :"car"}}} , {'vehicles.$':1}).pretty() `

Comment: update the answer with your code from last comment.